# WebKitErrorDomain error 101

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

The following code produces and error of:

```
WebKitErrorDomain error 101
```

code:

```
-(Void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked: (UISearchBar *) activeSearchBar { 
    NSString * query = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @ "" withString: @ "+"]; 
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "http://http://www.google.com/search?q =%, query]]; 
    NSURLRequest * requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url]; 
    [Home loadRequest: requestObj]; 
} 

-(Void) loadView { 
     [Super loadView]; 
     CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];   
     searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (0.0, 0.0, bounds.size.width, 48.0)]; 
     searchBar.delegate = self; 
     [Self.view addSubview: searchBar];
}
```

I don't speak english and rely on a translator. Because of the language issue could this be a keyboard problem, or an encoding problem?

Comment: The author stated that he did not speak english and relied on a "translator" presumably web based. I suggest you keep you answers very clear and avoid slang and vernacular so the translator will provide a cleaner translation.

Answer (score 5):

According to the WebKitError header, error 101 means, "WebKitErrorCannotShowURL" which is not very helpful.

This line is incorrect:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "http://http://www.google.com/search?q =%, query]];
```

... it should look like:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "http://www.google.com/search?q =%@", query]];
```

I'm not sure if that it causing the error by producing a bad URL or if it is a typo.

Answer (score 5):

Do not add whitespace in your string url.

Answer (score 2):

Make Sure that your url doesn't contain white space and new line characters.

To do this you can use the following code:

```
NSString *newString = [url stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```