# WebView Failed error in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to load website in webview.But i am getting error. Please correct me where i am wrong

URL  :  http://www.facebook.com/pages/Fresh-Caesar/144860502248864
 Error : The operation couldn’t be completed. (WebKitErrorDomain error 101.)

Answer (score 15):

We can resolve this problem by using string encoding

```
NSString *encodedString=[siteUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *weburl = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
```

Comment: even i encoded i got same error NSURLErrorDomain  code 1002 with encoded url %20 %21....  with in url.  and it say unsupported url

Comment: @kiran as per the [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793) it is returned when a properly formed URL cannot be handled by the framework. The most likely cause is that there is no available protocol handler for the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at [WebKitErrorDomain error 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194813/webkiterrordomain-error-101) for reference. Need to see more of your code though. Can you provide listing?

Comment: NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",facebook]];
   NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [self.webViewController loadRequest:request];