# FBwebdialogs, not showing on ios sdk - swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk, fbwebdialogs

Anyone else getting this error:

```
Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (WebKitErrorDomain error 101.)"
```

when using:

```
FBWebDialogs.presentDialogModallyWithSession(nil, dialog: "Share this", parameters: ["Sharing Tutorial": "name", "Build Great app": "Caption", "Users to share": "description", "http://google.ca":"link", "http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg": "picture"], handler: {
                result, resultURL, error in
                if (error != nil){
                    println("error publishing \(error.description)")
                } else {
                    if (result == FBWebDialogResult.DialogNotCompleted){
                        println("user cancelled")
                    } else {
                        println("very good job")
                    }
                }
```

Not really sure why this is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks SO

Comment: Error shows that there is an invalid url which can not handle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194813/webkiterrordomain-error-101

Answer (score 0):

In swift, doesn't the key come first? So your parameter dictionary is backwards.

```
["name": "Sharing Tutorial", "caption": "Build Great app", "description": "Users to share", "link": "http://google.ca", "picture": "http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg"]
```